# Slow Batch Upload to Google Sheets for Batch Upload of Records through Power Apps

Tags: google-sheets, powerapps

I am fairly new to Power Apps, and am trying to make a batch data entry form.

I am prototyping this now, and while I think in theory it should be working I keep running into technical errors.

The data source I'm using is google sheets. For prototyping purposes, there are three columns, item_id, item, and recorded_value.

For this app, it will be pulling a list of standard values into a gallery, where the input values can then be selected.

The approach I have taken is to create a gallery, which is added to a collection using the code below:

```
ClearCollect(
     collection, 
     ForAll(
          Filter(Gallery1.AllItems,true),
          { item:t_item.Text,item_id:t_item_id.Text,
           recorded_value:t_recorded_value.Text
          }
     )
)
```

This is then uploaded to google sheets, I have found "success" using the two methods below:

```
ForAll(collection,Patch(records, Defaults(records),{item:item,item_id:item_id,recorded_value:recorded_value}))
```

or

```
Collect(records, collection)
```

I would say overall I am seeing 2 main issues in the testing:

1. The initial 'collect' seems like it fails to capture items on occasion. I don't know if it is cache related or what, but it seems like unless I scroll all the way down it will leave some fields blank (maybe not an issue in real use, but seems odd)
2. Uploading of records seems to take excruciatingly long in some cases. While initially it was just straight up crashing due to the problems in issue 1, I have found that it will sometimes get to say item 85 before sitting for a minute or so and then going through the rest of the list. For just 99 items it is taking several minutes to upload.

Ultimately I am looking to know if there is a better approach for what I am doing. I am basically just wanting to take a max of 99 rows and paste it on to the table, but it feels really inefficient right now due to the looping nature of the function. I am not sure if this is more of a powerapps or google sheets issue, but any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I could research, it seems like batch upload of records like this is going to be time consuming nearly any way you approach it.

I was able to come up with a workaround however which more or less eliminates the problem.

Instead of uploading each individual record, I am taking the approach of concatenating all records in the collection in a single cell through a variable, using delimiters to differentiate the rows/columns. (set variable with concat function, then patch the variable to the data source.)

This method allows all of the data to be stored nearly instantaneously.

After that I am just going to perform some basic etl through Python to transform the data into a more standard format and load it into SQL server which is fairly trivial to do.

I recommend others looking to take a 'batch insert' approach try something similar, as it will now only take users essentially a second to load records rather than several minutes.